# Native tooltip of button not getting hidden after touch in IE Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, microsoft-edge

I have a simple 'Cancel' button  with the same tooltip (title) value, which closes using kendo method, inside Kendo popup. It works fine except in Microsoft Edge Browser, when touched. Post touch, the tooltip value doesn't goes away unless clicked anywhere else on the screen.

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" title="Cancel" onclick="javascript:closeWindow();">
```

Comment: First off, the `javascript:` part in the `onclick` attribute is pointless and you shouldn't be using `onclick` anyway. Please don't use 15 year old tutorials to learn JavaScript. And a dump suggestion: If the button already has the text "Cancel", do you really need a tooltip with the same text?

Comment: The code is legacy; the button is getting generated as a result of a HTML helper and thats why `javascript:`  part is necessary, otherwise it calls the controller. The `'Cancel'` tooltip needs to be there for some reasons. Anyways, I am not learning JavaScript.

Comment: _“and thats why javascript: part is necessary, otherwise it calls the controller”_ – that’s nonsense. `onclick="closeWindow();"` would not call anything but the JS function `closeWindow`.

Comment: To fix this behavior, I’d try to remove/empty the `title` attribute via JS – either only after the button is clicked (hoping that gets Edge to update display), otherwise, if that doesn’t work, beforehand (since as @RoToRa already said, a title that is identical to the text content doesn’t seem to provide that much value to begin with.)

Comment: @CBroe, as I mentioned, the DOM is getting generated via legacy HTML helper, so if one doesn't specifies anything for a method call like `onclick="closeWindow();"` so it calls the library controller and the DOM is like `onclick="NavigateTo("closeWindow();")"`. To be specific, one has to manually add prefix: `javascript` to ensure it will call only JS method. the solution provided by you is fine too, but what's the root cause which is causing the issue, is difficult to find. I think the problem with Edge browser is that, it sometimes doesn't recognizes the touch events.

Comment: If `onclick="closeWindow();"` is interpreted as `onclick="NavigateTo("closeWindow();")"`, then your whole system is very, very broken.

Comment: I do understand with you all, but I am prevented from making use of the best practices; instead just make the work done with minimum changes. I tried your solution too, but it didn't helped too.

Comment: I have been known to reject jobs on systems that are this broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Edge doesn't support touch events by default. It has an alternative system called pointer events. Sometimes 3rd party libs implement touch based widgets that don't play well with pointers. A quick way to determine if this is the case is to switch on touch events inside of Edge. Put `about:flags` in the address bar then go to the setting `enable touch event` and change it to always.

If the site now works, then I suspect it's an issue with the library. If that is the issue then I'd raise the issue with Telerik (the folk behind kendo) on their forums, they can probably help identify the issue specifically so that it can be fixed in the library.

Comment: Thank you Martin, I'll check and get back to you.